# Why can I not download OpenJDK-17 in my IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a Spring Boot application and I'm trying to set the JDK to OpenJDK-17. I've downloaded it from Java, then I go to **IDE and Project Settings** > **Project Structure** > SDKs, and then I click on the '**+**' > **Download JDK**. Then when I set the version to 17, I don't see OpenJDK-17 anywhere...

I get the following options:

Amazon Corretto *17.0.6*
Azul Zulu Community *17.0.6*
BellSoft Liberica JDK *17.0.5*
Eclipse Temurin (AdoptOpenJDK HotSpot) *17.0.5*
GraalVM Community Edition *17*
IBM Semeru (AdoptOpenJDK OpenJ9) *17.0.5*
SAP SapMachine *17.0.5*
---------**Other Versions**---------
Oracle OpenJDK *19.0.2*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for sure the rational of the Intellij for (no longer?) including a link to a "vanilla" OpenJDK 17 download site.  However my guess is that it is related to this notice on the https://jdk.java.net/17/ release page:

> ### JDK 17 Releases
>
> JDK 17 has been superseded. Please visit jdk.java.net for the current version.
>
> Older releases, **which do not include the most up to date security  vulnerability fixes and are no longer recommended for use in production,**  remain available in the OpenJDK Archive.

Note that the OpenJDK team are no longer publishing new builds for OpenJDK 17.  If you want the current Java 17 LTS build, you get it as an Oracle release or you get it from a 3rd-party vendor.  These should all include the most recent security patches.

The Intellij team would be doing users a **disservice** if they provided an easy way for users to download an old and potentially insecure OpenJDK Java 17 build.

Comment: and the current version is `Oracle OpenJDK 19.0.2` therefore it got it as suggestion under the list. This seems wrong however. I think if they provide all other distributors of OpenJdk in the list they could as well look here and offer the corresponding OpenJdk https://jdk.java.net/archive/

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos You shouldn't normally use the OpenJDK builds, you should use the builds of the different vendors. IntelliJ only shows *supported* builds, and OpenJDK 17.0.x is not supported. OpenJDK only "supports" a version for the first 6 months of a major version, after that support is only available through the different vendors.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Your explanation makes sense, is there a link where they explicitly state they support each version just for first 6 months?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos - The OpenJDK team doesn't "support" any release!  Reread Mark's comment.  If you want something that is supported, you get it from a vendor.   What OpenJDK does do is to issue new patch builds for 6 months.  I haven't found an explicit link that states this, but it should be obvious from looking at what is in the OpenJDK download archive area; see https://jdk.java.net/archive/

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos I remember reading about it in the past, but right now I can't find a clear policy statement.

Comment: The OpenJDK team "could have" decided to release ongoing patch builds for Java 17, etc. But instead they are using their resources / man-power for doing the stuff that they are best at; i.e. working on new Java platform development. There is really no point in them publishing the latest Java 17 patch builds, given that users can get the builds from other at least 7 other places.   (More if you include various Linux distro, etc package repositories.)

Comment: @StephenC How does this work with the LTS support from vendors like IBM?  Semeru 17 is supported through 31 Oct 2027 and getting regular security patches.  IntelliJ only lets us get back to version 18 today, which ironically will be out of support before the 17 LTS version.

Comment: @Ukko - I don't know what you mean by "how does it work".  If you have a beef with the way that the Intellij team deals with OpenJDK releases, contact them. If you have a beef with the fact that the OpenJDK team doesn't support OpenJDK builds past the next release, contact them.  I'm not associated with either team in any way.

Comment: Or ... use one of the other **vendor supported** Java 17 releases ... and don't expect a supported release from a source (OpenJDK) that doesn't offer support.

Comment: @StephenC that is precisely my point.  IBM is still providing vender support and will for years to come, but IntelliJ is removing them on the OpenJDK timeline and not the vendor's timeline.  The vendor which is providing the very support you claim to be worried about in this case.

Comment: Huh?   "**IBM** Semeru (AdoptOpenJDK OpenJ9) 17.0.5"   (Or are you saying that IBM is also distributing non-Semeru Java 17.0.5?  If so ... is it a publicly accessible download?  Have you asked Intellij why it is not on their list?)

Answer (score 4):

OpenJDK is basically a source only project (though they do release reference binaries for the first six months, which usually results in three releases, e.g. 17.0.0 - 17.0.2). After those three months, newer releases are only available through the vendors (e.g. for Java 17.0.5). All those listed **are** variants of OpenJDK 17 (except IBM Semeru, which is OpenJ9, which itself is a variant of OpenJDK). And bar vendor specific extras, or optional features like garbage collectors, they are basically the same, and have been tested for compliance with the Java specification.

In the Java world, you pick a vendor, and use its binaries instead of the binaries from OpenJDK itself (which generally don't go further then x.0.2, while vendor specific versions continue to receive updates if they are LTS versions). Personally, I usually use Eclipse Temurin builds.